# LoaderManager not initializing... a issue with getLoaderManager().initLoader

Tags: android, loader, android-loadermanager

I know there is a lot of common questions like this out there but I just can't seem to find the solution. When I attempt to initialize my loader using `getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);` The error The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, Gridview) comes up.

This leads me to believe that the program is not recognizing that Gridview implements the loader manager. I'm not sure why this is and where to go from here. I tried playing around with different imports but that didn't work. I also made sure I had the proper downloads to support loaders. The code I am using is below.

```
package com.example.camerapreview;

import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;

//Omissis imports


public class Gridview extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{       
    private static final String TAG = "Checking Database";
    private static final String TAG1 = "Checking Thumbnail";

    Cursor cursor;
    int columnindexid;
    int columnindexdata;
    int videoidindex;
    int videopathindex;
    GridviewData entry;
    GridView gridview;
    VideoAdapter videoadapter;
    Cursor curs;

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config;

    String[] mediaColumns = {
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE
    };

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
    int flags = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preview);
        gridview = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridview);


        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mediaColumns, null, null, null);
        columnindexid = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
        columnindexdata = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

        entry = new GridviewData(this);
        entry.open();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        DataEntry putitin = new DataEntry(entry, this);
        putitin.execute();

        //the cursor used in the cursor adapater
        curs = entry.adapterCursor();
        videoidindex = entry.Indexfinder(curs);
        videopathindex = entry.Indexfinder2(curs);

        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(this))
                        .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        Log.i(TAG, "Before set adapater");
        gridview.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this, curs, flags));
     }
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { GridviewData.VIDEOID, GridviewData.VIDEOFILEPATH };
    return new CursorLoader(Gridview.this, MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
    cursoradapter.swapCursor(c);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursoradapter.swapCursor(null);     
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing the rest of inherited functions? (onCreateLoader,onLoadFinished,onLoaderReset)

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: I see nothing strange but the imports of your loaderManager do you realy need support v4 version? mine is `import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;`

Comment: Tried that import out and it didn't work. Something else to note is that when i use getActivity() instead of Gridview.this in the onCreateLoader there is an error of The method getActivity() is undefined for the type Gridview. I don't know if this would realte to this issue.

Comment: I think that it is because getActivity() is for fragments. Change your v4 imports for `android.app.` imports and change getActivity() for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is caused by your imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
```

they would be fine for `FragmentActivity` but you are using a normal `Activity` so they should be:

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
```

Please note that in this case your `android:minSdkVersion` should be 11. If you need compatibility with lower versions, just keep the imports as they are and use `FragmentActivity`.